# Find $\lambda$ and solve the matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Find $\lambda$ and solve the matrix. I have 4 equations:

\begin{cases}
x+y+z-t=2\\
x+y-z+t=2\\
3x+y+z+t=\lambda\\
x-y+z+t=2\\
\end{cases}
I've got $$t=\frac{\lambda -6}{4}; \ z=\frac{6-\lambda}{4};\ y=\frac{\lambda -6}{4}; \ x=\frac{2+\lambda}{4}$$

What I did wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. Substitute it in the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

After adding of the first, second and forth equations we'll get $$3x+y+z+t=6,$$ which gives $\lambda=6.$

Comment: But using Gauss I can't get this solution?

Comment: @J.Doe Which says that there is a mistake in your computations.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is $$x=2-t,y=t,z=t$$ and $$\lambda=6$$

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting eq. 2 from both eq. 1 and eq. 4 gives 
\begin{cases}
2z-2t=0\\
x+y-z+t=2\\
3x+y+z+t=\lambda\\
-2y+2z=0\\
\end{cases}
Which implies
$$\begin{cases}
z=t\\
x=2-y\\
6-3y+3y=\lambda\\
y=z=t\\
\end{cases}\implies \lambda = 6$$